# TFS work item query by linked worked items?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, bug-tracking

Let's say I have a bunch of bugs (work items) that are all linked one work item.  How can I right a work item query to fetch the list of all bugs linked to a specific work item?

I can see the list of linked bugs when I look at the specific work item but I'd like to be able to create a query for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS 2008 you can't do that with a work item query.  TFS 2010 provides this support out the box, along with the ability to view that query in a shiney tree view.  If you fancy having a play with Beta 1 of TFS 2010 then you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=58665c27-7023-4a50-b31d-c39cd86a415f&displaylang=en)

However, don't be tempted to install as a production server just yet as it is still a beta.

Comment: Sounds like what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this using a low level WIQL API, but through the standard query UI there is no way to do this.